# How do I change certain page titles?

Tags: 6

How do I change certain page titles in Drupal, most notably the *create new account*, *log in*, and *request new password* tab headings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the strings used in Drupal, you can use string overrides: Add code similar to the following one, at the bottom of the settings.php file used by your Drupal site.

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
  'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
  '@count min' => '@count minutes',
);
```

The description given for strings overrides in the settings.php file is the following:

> String overrides:
>
> To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling locale module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows you to change a small number of your site's default English language interface strings.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Do you know why it works on 'User account' title, but not the 'Request new password'? The 'Request new password' only change the tabs title and not the page title.

Answer (score 3):

you can `create a module`. inside the module you can use the function form_alter to modify the form, and specifically use the function `drupal_set_title()` to add the title, for example:

create a module with the name "change_title".
add a form_alter function (note that the name of the module is added to the _form_alter name function)

```
function change_title_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

 //dsm($form_id) this function is to know the $form_id

   if ($form_id == 'content_type_node_form') {
       drupal_set_title('this is my new title');
   }

}
```

note: about how to get the $form_id value, you can use Devel module to use the function dsm($form_id), then the return of this function will show you the $form_id value.

Comment: OK... but is there a simpler way to achieve this? I'm not really the module-creating type ;-)

Comment: sorry, I do not know other easy way, but if you review how to start a module, you will find that is very easy, in few words is just to create one directory and also create two files, then add the code inside one of this files (the .module file): see a 'howto' http://drupal.org/node/231276

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this as it may be helpful for other projects...

Answer (score 2):

The [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module will do this.

From the project page:

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

It also has versions for both D6 and D7.